# open bin 16-bit right aligned

Tags: matlab, binary, precision, fread

I'm trying to open an image file with MATLAB (R2011b). The program which stored the bin file (Xeneth) says it has the datatype "Images (16-bit right aligned) (*.png;*.csv;*.bin)".

In MATLAB, I'm trying to open the file with:

```
fid=fopen('pathAndFile','r');
A=fread(fid,'inf','uint16');
```

Unfortunately, it keeps saying "Error using fread Invalid precision."
An example file can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d8pj1lrhjsnbmvx/mHSdark_20ms_00014.bin

Does someone have an idea what could cause the problem?

Comment: [imread](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) wont read it either?

Comment: Unfortunately not. As far as I understood, imread can't read binary

Comment: I guess it would be easier to check what is happening if you could provide example of your file.

Comment: The [CORRECT ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21791189/2778484) for anyone who runs into the same problem: It should be `inf` without the quotes (a numeric infinity, not a string `'inf'`). You can just remove this input argument and it will read to the end too, but don't think it's a problem with `fread`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same error message in Octave and removing `'inf'` solved the problem

```
close all; clear all;

fid = fopen('mHSdark_20ms_00014.bin');
A = fread(fid, 'uint16');
fclose(fid);

size(A)
```

Here is an execution result

```
octave:5> test
ans =

   20480       1
```

Comment: removing 'inf' did the job. Instead of it, its possible to use the correct sizeA [m,n]. eg: A=fread(fid,[64,320],'uint16');

Answer (score 1):

This is because the optional size argument of [`fread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) is a *numeric*, not a string.  That is, instead of `'inf'`, the appropriate input is just `inf`, a number, not a string. When you input a string to `fread`, it thinks you are specifying a precision instead of a size.

However, the default size is `inf`, which is why the argument may be omitted.